# I have a OVG video that I want to put into my site

Tags: html, video, ogg

I have a OVG video and I would like to put that into my site. I do not know much about that file format so I am concerned how it will be with cross browser compatibility. I know that FF will play the file yet I am unsure about IE (I am only worrying about IE 8+)

What is the best way to put this file into my site? Should I use the HTML 5 `<video>` tag or should I use another format? I need this to work with IE 8 so I am unsure what the best route is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use video element, with multiple source elements inside, each pointing to a different format of your .ovg file. you can generate cross-browser files at [media.io](http://media.io/) or via [Miro converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) (download). the *best* way would be to degrade gracefully for older browsers, you'll want to provide some JavaScript, [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) is my preferred lib, you can use their embed builder tool, that'll provide the older fallbacks

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly for me using the links and the VideoJS code.

Answer (score 1):

For the best compatibility, you'll want to use a video hosting site and embed the Flash video into the site. If you want to host it yourself, you'll have to find a Flash video player that you can use, but I'm pretty sure most or all of those are commercial.

Otherwise you'll need to have both an H264 version (MP4) and an OGG version and include both versions in the source tag. You can then also include a fallback to a Flash embedded version.

You can [find out more here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-html-5-video-with-a-fallback-to-flash/).